# Determining whether an operator has maximal rank

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, lie-algebras

Consider the following

> We showed that Lie point symmetries are useful for solving ODE's and PDE's. But how do we find them the first place?
>
> 5.4.1 Trivial Case
> Lets try to find Lie point symmetries of an 0th order ODE
> $$
> \Delta[x, u]=0 .
> $$
> By definition $g^{\varepsilon}:(x, u) \mapsto(\tilde{x}, \tilde{u})$ is a Lie point symmetry if
> $$
> \Delta[x, u]=0 \quad \Longrightarrow \Delta[\tilde{x}, \tilde{u}]=\Delta\left[g^{\varepsilon}(x, u)\right]=0 .
> $$
> Question: Can we reduce this to a statement about the generator of $g^{\varepsilon}$ ?
> The answer is yes, but will need to assume that $\Delta$ is of maximal rank.
>
> Defn (Maximal Rank) The operator $\Delta$ is of maximal rank if the matrix of derivatives
> $$
> \frac{\partial \Delta_j}{\partial y_i}
> $$
> is of maximal rank, where the $y_i$ runs over $x, u$, and in general all coordinates.

The definition makes no sense to me. The text gives
$$
    \Delta[x, u] = x^{2}.
$$
as an operator which does not have maximal rank.  The issue for me is that this is not a vector, so how can I take its $i$-th component?

**Question:** Could someone clarify here what the partial derivatives mean with this indentation?